# Проблема с файлом wsgi.py (Problem with wsgi.py file)

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

The error log that pythonanywhere prints

> !2020-03-29 21:29:25,095: Error running WSGI application
>   2020-03-29 21:29:25,095: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
>   2020-03-29 21:29:25,095:   File "/var/www/relizerel_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 22, in 
>   2020-03-29 21:29:25,095:     application = get_wsgi_application()
>
> !2020-03-29 21:29:25,095:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
>   2020-03-29 21:29:25,095:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
>
> !2020-03-29 21:29:25,096:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 19, in setup
>   2020-03-29 21:29:25,096:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
>
> !2020-03-29 21:29:25,096:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 79, in **getattr**
>   2020-03-29 21:29:25,096:     self._setup(name)
>
> !2020-03-29 21:29:25,096:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 66, in _setup
>   2020-03-29 21:29:25,096:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>
> !2020-03-29 21:29:25,097:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 176, in **init**
>   2020-03-29 21:29:25,097:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

My settings.py file

```py
"""
Django settings for myshop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = *************

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['relizerel.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# default static files settings for PythonAnywhere.
# see https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles for more info
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/relizerel/myshop/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/relizerel/myshop/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My wsgi.py file

```py
"""
WSGI config for myshop project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myshop.settings.dev")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I think the problem is in SECRET KEY, but in all files it is indicated.

What other data is needed to make it easier for you to give an answer?

I added Wagtail CMS after creating a standard web application.
However, collectstatic, makemigrations and migrate did not return any errors

Link to my repository on GitHub: https://github.com/relizerel/myshopwt.git

Comment: Don’t paste your secret key, it’s a security risk

Comment: ok, thanks, i'll know

Comment: You need to invalidate your key and get another one, as the edit log will now contain your current one.

Comment: Is the settings file you posted the same settings file that your wsgi file points to: `myshop.settings.dev` ?

Comment: Filip, Dragonthoughts, thanks! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your django settings.py file has no `SECRET_KEY`. You may have to define this as an environment variable or explicitly in your code depending on how your `settings.py` is written.

As per your wsgi.py file, it is referring to `myshop/settings/dev.py`. Make sure the `SECRET_KEY` is in that settings file, or when running gunicorn (or whatever you use to deploy the server) that you set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the actual settings file with the `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: Show us your `settings.py` and I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: I checked all the files where the secret key is found and in all the files it is

Comment: Is `SECRET_KEY` an actual string or is it pulling from the environment variables?

Comment: Okay, so it is defined. Can you share your `wsgi.py` file as well?

Comment: GrandPhuba, +1, Thanks

Comment: Do you have a file named `myshop/settings/dev.py`? If not let me know, and tell me the contents of the directory `myshop/`

Comment: yes, I have this file in the settings folder, it was necessary to delete the same file from another directory.